# Calculating the mean for a set of numbers while neglecting outliers

Tags: c++, math

First of all this is more of a math question than it is a coding one, so please be patient.
I am trying to figure out an algorithm to calculate the mean for a set of numbers. However I need to neglect any numbers that are not close to the majority of the results. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

Lets say I have a set of numbers that are similar to the following:

```
{ 90, 91, 92, 95, 2, 3, 99, 92, 92, 91, 300, 91, 92, 99, 400 }
```

it is clear for the set above that the majority of numbers lies between `90` and `99`, however I have some outliers like `{ 300, 400, 2, 3 }`. I need to calculate the mean of those numbers while neglecting the outliers. I do remember reading about something like that in a statistics class but I cant remember what was it or how to approach the solution.

Will appreciate any help..

Thanks

Comment: I've edited your question to talk about "outliers" rather than "odd numbers", which could be interpreted as something quite different!

Comment: yeah thanks, was looking for the right word for those myself

Comment: I liked the usage of term [`outlier`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) here, which is usually used in [`Black swan theory`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory)

Comment: In order to deal with outliers, you could compute the median rather than the mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10858/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do is:

1. estimate the percentage of outliers in your data: about 25% (4/15) of the provided dataset,
2. compute the adequate quantiles: 8-quantiles for your dataset, so as to exclude the outliers,
3. estimate the mean between the first and the last quantile.

PS: Outliers constituting 25% of your dataset is a lot!

PPS: For the second step, we assumed outliers are "symmetrically distributed". See the graph below, where we use 4-quantiles and 1.5 times the interquartile range (IQR) from Q1 and Q3:[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I completely forgot about the IQR thx a lot

Comment: Oh and the set given here is just an example, its not the real case.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that IQR stands for [interquartile range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to determine the standard deviation and mean of the full set. The outliers are those values that are greater than 3 standard deviations from the (full set) mean.

Comment: The problem with this method is that the outliers skew the estimation of the standard deviation. For methods that are more robust to the outliers, see my answer.

Comment: This is a trimmed mean, but as static_rtti remarked, using the standard deviation instead of a fixed limit is not a priori relevant for a non-normal distribution.

Comment: This method is suitable only for large data sets and strong assumptions about eg. the normality of the data distribution. For most problems, it is not enough.

Comment: I would go further and say there is no valid reason to base the mean on only those values which are not considered outliers -- but I was answering the original question, rather than criticizing the idea. Outliers _do_ happen and _are_ valid, and a valid mean on a set of data should not discard them. Any attempt to do so will skew the results, so it comes down to: what kind of skew do you want your results to have?

Comment: @mah : the question of outliers completely depends on the application. If you have a faulty sensor (for example), outliers are invalid and should be discarded. Why not try to answer the OP's question instead of trying to guess what he really needs to do? Give the OP the benefit of doubt.

Comment: @static_rtti: I did answer his question, without trying to guess what he needs... please read the answer I gave (and feel free to tell me if I've made an error in it or interpreting what he asked). I gave him 100% benefit of the doubt, just as you did in your answer.

Comment: I was commenting on your previous comment. I think we agree :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple method that works well is to take the median instead of the average. The median is far more robust to outliers.

You could also minimize a Geman-McClure function:

```
x^ = argmin sum( G(xi - x')), where G(x) = x^2/(x^2+sigma^2)
```

If you plot the G function, you will find that it saturates, which is a good way of softly excluding outliers.

Comment: Your answer sounds acceptable (I'm not saying it is) but it is clear that that you are speaking statistical jargon. As far as I can tell, I think @Red Serpent is not a statistician. Maybe you should explain what those terms (Geman-McClure function et al) mean and how to implement them. You will be doing us some good. Thanks

Comment: @afaolek thanks I was just about to ask the same question though I was googling about ArgMin to see how to calculate it.

Comment: There is an awfully huge step from computing a (twisted) mean or median to minimizing a high-dimensional function, however smooth. If you can edit your answer to provide a closed form solution to this optimization problem (or a simple algorithm), then it will be useful. Otherwise, it is overly complex for the problem at hand.

Comment: I gave the formula, what more do you want? If you tell me what you don't understand, I can try to explain more.

Comment: @Alexandre C. : what high-dimensional function? The function to minimize only has one parameter, assuming the data is one dimensional (which is the case in the OP's question). I'm not pretending this is the best solution for every problem, just giving it as an example of what can be done.

Comment: BTW thanks to the person who downvoted my post. I think next time I will keep my knowledge to myself.

Comment: @static_rtti: sorry, it is indeed one-dimensional. But expensive to compute (and to minimize). I doubt this scales well with the data.

Comment: @static_rtti: Also, what do you choose as sigma ?

Comment: It depends on the minimizer you use, and obviously on the size of the data. I'm pretty sure you could solve it in less than a second even for pretty large datasets (again, this is 1D data). If speed is an issue, I mentioned taking the median; I wanted to show the two ends of the spectrum of possible solutions.

Comment: Sigma is a constant that encodes the variability of the real data, excluding the outliers.

Comment: If you plot the function I think you will understand how it works.

Comment: @static_rtti: so finding what to put as sigma involves some thoughtful work, and some preliminary analysis. What are the advantages of this approach compared to a recipe like @wok's which has the advantage of not requiring a minimization algorithm ? (formally, it minimizes sum(G(x - xi)) with G = x^2 when x < sigma, 0 otherwise, but the method is direct)

Comment: It avoids making a binary decision on what is an outlier and what isn't. Whether it is better or not depends on the application.

Comment: Note that for wok's answer to minimize your expression, you would have to make it iterative, and even then, you wouldn't be sure of reaching the global minimum. So it does indeed (formally) require a minimization algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very careful about this.  You could be doing yourself and your conclusions a great disservice.

How is your program supposed to recognize outliers?  The normal distribution would say that 99.9% of the values fall within +/- three standard deviations of the mean, so you could calculate both for the unfiltered data, exclude the values that fall outside the assumed range, and recalculate.

However, you might be throwing away something significant by doing so.  The normal distribution isn't sacred; outliers are far more common in real life than the normal distribution would suggest.  Read Taleb's ["Black Swan"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/081297381X) to see what I mean.

Be sure you understand fully what you're excluding before you do so.  I think it'd be far better to leave all the data points, warts and all, and come up with a good written explanation for them.

Another approach would be a use an alternate measure like median, which is less sensitive to outliers than mean.  It's harder to calculate, though.